# HTML5 input pattern для ДНК

Tags: регулярные-выражения, html5

Есть следующая форма, которая принимает три последовательности ДНК, 2 коротких, 1 длинную:

```
<form class="dna_form" action="/treat.php" method="post" name="dna_form">
    <ul>
        <li>
             <h2>Введите данные</h2>
             <span class="required_notification">* Обязательные поля для заполнения</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="primer1">Первый праймер:</label>
            <input type="text"  name="primer1" placeholder="AGTCAGTCAGTC" required />
            <span class="form_hint">Правильный формат включает только A,G,T,C</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="primer2">Второй праймер:</label>
            <input type="text" name="primer2" placeholder="AGTCAGTCAGTC" required />
            <span class="form_hint">Правильный формат включает только A,G,T,C</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="dna">Фрагмент ДНК:</label>
            <textarea name="dna" cols="40" rows="6" placeholder="AGTCAGTCAGTC" required ></textarea>
            <span class="form_hint">Правильный формат включает только A,G,T,C</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button class="submit" type="submit">Подобрать</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Добавил проверку полей через pattern вида                 `<input type="text" name="primer2" placeholder="AGTCAGTCAGTC" required pattern = "[A-Za-z]{12,}"/>` - использовать только латинские буквы, не менее 12 штук. Но хочется большего, а именно: чтобы можно было ввести только буквы a,g,t,c и A, G, T, C, но не могу подобрать правильный паттерн - всё, что вставлял, не работает :( Или так не получится и нужно делать проверку через JavaScript?

Comment: `[AGTCagtc]{12,}`?

Comment: @InDevX этот, точнее [agtcAGTC]{12,} пробовал сразу же - вылезает ошибка "illegal symbol code"

Comment: на jsfiddle всё работает.. тогда js

Comment: Только JS, ибо у `<textarea>`  всё равно нет атрибута **pattern**.

Comment: @UModeL угу. Правда, onChange для срабатывание нужно, чтобы TEXTAREA потерял фокус :(

Comment: @AlexeyKozlov: почти все поля можно проверять через onInput.